# Have any way to let the drawer navigator Item not be show

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-navigation

I don't want to let all routers show the itemView. It is because that there are some routers I need custom the item in other position.Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if I understood your question right. I looked a long time for a way to disable or hide certain drawer items to only navigate to through a custom link. I didn't find a simple way to do this in the React navigation docs. Instead, I created a custom drawer and created all of the links myself.

I gave a longer answer to a similar question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205159/8071132.

Comment: Oh!Thanks you help. But I have found a solution that I change the reducer of the drawer navigator