# Sidebar menu in React Native with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` in `React Native` and I want to create a sidebar menu which opens as an overlay that comes from left to the right and fills up around 80-90% of the width.

Without react-navigation, this is possible with packages such as `react-native-side-bar`, but I am wondering if I can get the exact same feature with DrawerNavigator.

But it seems DrawerNavigator has menu buttons. Isn't it possible to configure the overlay myself?

## Edit

#### Solution 1

One way would be to use

```
const MyStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  A: { screen: AScreen },
  B: { screen: BScreen },
  C: { screen: CScreen }
});

const RootNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  A: { screen: MyStackNavigator },
}, {
  // set content of side bar
  contentComponent: (props) => <Sidebar />
});
```

but then it will possible to drag in the drawer from all screens `AScreen`, `BScreen`, and `CScreen`, while I only want it to be there for `AScreen`, since the StackNavigator is nested in the DrawerNavigator.

#### Solution 2

Another solution would be to use

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  A: { screen: AScreen },
}, {
  // set content of side bar
  contentComponent: (props) => <Sidebar />
});

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  A: { screen: MyDrawerNavigator },
  B: { screen: BScreen },
  C: { screen: CScreen }
});
```

but then the header of `AScreen` will be on top since the DrawerNavigator is nested in `A`.

Comment: How is what you're trying to do different than what the DrawerNavigator does by default? Looking at the example for `react-native-side-bar` they're doing the same thing.

Comment: It is the exact same. The problem is how to organize the navigators. I have updated my question with an example

Answer (score 5):

I needed the same functionality that you're describing and managed to get it working with React navigation. Basically, I needed a fully custom drawer (side-menu).

This is my navigator setup:

```
const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      Search: {
        screen: SearchScreen
      },
      Result: {
        screen: ResultScreen
      }
    })
  },
  Saved: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      SavedStack: {
        screen: SavedWordsScreen
      }
    })
  },
  About: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      AboutStack: {
        screen: AboutScreen
      }
    })
  }
},{
  contentComponent: props => (<Drawer navigation={props.navigation} drawerProps={{...props}} />)
});
```

As you see, I've created a Drawer component which contains my custom drawer content. This is the basic setup of that component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class Drawer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Search" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')} />
            <Button title="Saved" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Saved')} />
            <Button title="About" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')} />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. I've simplified some of the code to mainly show the relevant bits so if you have any follow-up questions, just ask!

Comment: Thanks. But I have already tried this and what I experienced is that in all your screens, you are able to active the drawer by swiping in the left side of the screen. I want the drawer to only stay in, for instance, your `Home`. I am afraid it's not possible with `react-navigation`

Comment: @Jamgreen - here's a post I wrote showing how to do this with a drawer that stays open: https://medium.com/@seansy/building-a-pinned-left-nav-with-react-navigation-406fdb0f120.  If you want to be able to open/close you can integrate react-native-reanimated with PanGestureHandler as React Navigation does here: https://github.com/react-navigation/drawer/blob/5fb664ea67cb213bf95664a1da0f5422637f61cf/src/views/Drawer.tsx#L514